# umount a busy device without killing process?

Tags: linux, mount

I want to change the mount point of /tmp.  However there are several processes keeping it busy.  Is there a way to umount without killing those processes?  e.g. suspending them etc.

Comment: imho, you can't do this without disrupting  processes which might having temporary data in the previous location that might be vital to their survival.

Comment: No, unless you are really really good with `gdb` and even then yeah just kill the processes and remount, or reboot the box with the new mount.

Comment: Which kernel (Linux, *BSD, etc.)?

Comment: it's CentOS 7 @derobert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a lazy un-mount (`umount -l`), which will detach the mount from `/tmp`. You can then mount whatever other filesystem you'd like on `/tmp`. Note that the old `/tmp` will still be mounted, just not visible (except to those few processes still using it). It'll eventually be unmounted when those processes stop using it. So, e.g., it'd be a bad idea to `mkfs` the underlying storage.

Another alternative (if it works, depends on which of your mounts have "shared" propagation) is `mount --move` to move the mount to a different directory (e.g., `mkdir /oldtmp; mount --move /tmp /oldtmp;`); then you can again mount a new filesystem on `/tmp`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mount seems to have shared propagation.  I received the error `bad option. Note that moving a mount residing under a shared mount is unsupported` when I tried `mount --move`.  What's the cause of this error?  Is it because it's shared by NFS?

Comment: @roymaztang shared refers to between mount namespaces, which is a container feature. Nothing to do with NFS. You should still be able to lazy unmount it.